# Java program to pass List of Bean to a oracle stored procedure - Pass entire list at one shot rather than appending objects one after the other

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, bulk-load, oracle-type

I have the following set of TYPE, PROCEDURE and Java code. I am able to call the stored procedure successfully but i have to append the objects one after the other. I want the process to be happening at one shot as i am dealing with over 50K+ records. Can anyone please let me know what changes needs to be done so that i can send the entire list at one. The code can be found below.

```
TYPES: 
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE AS OBJECT
                      (idKey NUMBER(10)  );

    CREATE or REPLACE TYPE CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST AS TABLE OF  CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE;

PROCEDURE:

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES (
       p_array    IN     CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST ,p_status      OUT VARCHAR2)
    AS
       v_count      NUMBER(5);
       row_detail   CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE;
    BEGIN
       --p_arr_int := NEW array_int ();
       --p_arr_int.EXTEND (10);
       --len := p_array.COUNT;
       v_count := 0;

       FOR i IN 1 .. p_array.COUNT
       LOOP
          row_detail := p_array (i);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('hello');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (row_detail.idKey);
          --p_arr_int (i) := v_count;
          v_count := v_count + 1;
          p_status := 'true';
       END LOOP;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_count);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_status);
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          -- handle errors here...
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error: ' || SUBSTR (1, 255, SQLERRM));
    END;
    /

Java Bean:

    import java.sql.SQLData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.SQLInput;
    import java.sql.SQLOutput;

    public class SampleListenerBean implements SQLData
    {
        private String sql_type="CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE";

        private int id;

        public SampleListenerBean() {

        }

        public SampleListenerBean(String sqlType, int id) {
            this.sql_type = sqlType;
            this.id = id;
        }




        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


        public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
            return sql_type; 
        }

        public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
            sql_type = typeName;

            id = stream.readInt();
        }

        public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
            stream.writeInt(id);
        }
    }

Main class: 

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class StProcExample {



    public static void main(String args[]){
            Connection con=null;
            try{
                 DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver ());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@******:1521: TUW1", "*******", "*********");
            String query = "{call GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES(?,?)}";


            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);
            ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST", con);

            List<SampleListenerBean> sampleLst = new ArrayList<SampleListenerBean>();

            SampleListenerBean bean = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                bean = new SampleListenerBean("CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE",i);
                sampleLst.add(bean);
            }


            SampleListenerBean emp=new SampleListenerBean("TS.TEST_EMP_OBJ",234);
            SampleListenerBean emp1=new SampleListenerBean("TS.TEST_EMP_OBJ",235);
            Object[] employees= new Object[]{emp,emp1};
            Object[] employees= new Object[]{sampleLst};
            ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, employees);
            cs.setObject(1, (Object)a);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.execute();

            String status = cs.getString(2);

            System.out.print("The status is " + status);
            if (cs != null) {
                cs.close();
             }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

I want is the replacement for the following piece of code

```
    SampleListenerBean emp=new SampleListenerBean("TS.TEST_EMP_OBJ",234);
    SampleListenerBean emp1=new SampleListenerBean("TS.TEST_EMP_OBJ",235);
    Object[] employees= new Object[]{emp,emp1};

    ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, employees);
    cs.setObject(1, (Object)a);
```

Instead of setting each object separately, i want to directly use sampleLst instead of the Object array "employees". When i deal with 50K+ objects i cannot keep adding them to the object[]. i will run into heap problems as well. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a simpler table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUM_ARRAY AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

And then somewhat simplify the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES (
   p_array    IN     NUM_ARRAY,
   p_status   OUT    VARCHAR2)
IS
...
```

You then create an array of `Integer` that will easily fit in memory:

```
Integer[] idArray = new Integer[50000];

// fill the array of integers here
for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++)
    idArray[i] = ....;

ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, idArray);
cs.setObject(1, (Object)a);
```

There's no need to create any heavy-weight beans just to pass a list of IDs.

Comment: Actually i have put a sample program to accept only one parameter. My original problem is i have to send in multiple data in a single array. I will end up with multiple dimensional array. Hence i have a bean. Can this be dealt with?

Comment: When i do SampleListenerBean emp = new SampleListenerBean("CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE", 234);
   SampleListenerBean emp1 = new SampleListenerBean("CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE", 235); Object[] employees = new Object[] { emp,emp1 };    
   ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, employees); The procedure is called successfully, but when i add the same beans to a List and then use Object[] employees= new Object[]{sampleLst.toArray()}; ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con, employees);  i get the following exception java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types. Why is that so? Is there no way i can use List?

Comment: Oh, multi-dimensional data is hard (or maybe even impossible). If it can be done, then you'll need an object type with an array/table as one of the members (on the Oracle side) and the use of STRUCT on the Java side.

Comment: `Object[] employees= new Object[]{sampleLst.toArray()};` is not what you want. It creates an array with one element containing another array. Try `Object[] employees = sampleLst.toArray();` instead.

Comment: With Object[] employees = sampleLst.toArray(); my procedure returns The status is null, I had to get The status is true instead

Comment: My bad, i had commented put a piece of code. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot Codo. 100 *'s to you.

Comment: I have been trying to enhance the above procedure and am confused in the implementation. Rather than VARCHAR2 as a output from the procedure i now want to return NUM_ARRAY as the output from the procedure. Can you please help me in implementing the logic to read the NUM_ARRAY in my java code. Normally output is returned using Map out = super.execute(inParams); How can i now extract the NUM_ARRAY to my bean?

Comment: If you have code like `Map out = super.execute(inParams);`, then you're probably not using the standard JDBC classes and methods but some other SQL library on top of JDBC. It's difficult to help you without knowing what you actually use.

Comment: I am trying to execute using Spring stored procedure.Please find below my implementation. Due to lack of space i am splitting the implementation into 2 comments. public boolean execute(final Bean bean, final DataSource ds) throws Exception { boolean retVal = false; Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>(); inParams.put("IN_ARRAY", new SqlTypeValue() { public void setTypeValue(PreparedStatement cs, int index, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {Connection con = cs.getConnection(); Connection con = cs.getConnection();

Comment: ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("PROD_PRCT_BRKDWN_TYPE_ARRAY", con); ARRAY a = new ARRAY(des, con,bean.getxlLst().toArray()); cs.setObject(1, (Object)a); } }); inParams.put("OUT_ARRAY", ?what should this be?); } Map out = super.execute(inParams); // how to get the same array as value Boolean.parseBoolean((String)out.get(o));
} return returnVal;}

Comment: Please create a new question. It makes no sense to put so much code into comments.

Comment: I have created a new question as asked. The question can be found under the following location. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937775/how-to-read-a-array-of-types-returned-from-a-stored-proc-using-java)

Comment: @sandy: I'm sorry but I don't sufficiently understand the JDBC part of the Spring framework to help you with your new question. I could give an example for plain JDBC.

Comment: any code would be helpful. I will try and convert it to the spring framework compatible version.